# R ggplotly producing correct plot, but when moving to plot.ly, x-axis is different

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

Producing a plotly object using ggplotly returns exactly what I need, however, when using api_create() and pushing the object to plotly online, the x-axis appears as numeric, and not a factor as I declared it to be in R.

```
mem$Office <- as.factor(mem$Office)
mem_plot <- ggplot(data=mem,aes(x=Office,y=Total, fill=Office)) + 
geom_bar(size=mem$Total,width=0.5,position='dodge',stat='identity') + 
labs(x = 'Office', y = 'Total')

mem_plot <- ggplotly(mem_plot,tooltip=c("x","y"))

mem_plot
```

Which returns: [image]

Then I run: `api_create(mem_plot, filename = "memership-plot")`

And get this from plot.ly: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Needed to adjust the ggplotly() command.

```
mem_plot <- ggplotly(mem_plot, dynamicTicks = T)
```